# How to get more then one thousand(1000) record from RESHTHEART?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, datatables, angular-datatables, restheart

I am using [RESTHEART](http://restheart.org/#) for accessing the service(API) and using NoSQL  database mongoDB. So In MongoDb, I have 9000 records. If I am calling through **RESTHEART** then It is returning maximum only one thousand. So In one hit I am getting less then 10001 records. If I want to retrieve all records then I have to send again one more call.

**I am attaching one flow of restheart and MongoDb**
[image]

So based on restheart I am implementing angular data-table.

```
 <table datatable dt-options="datatables.standardOptions" dt-columns="datatables.standardColumns" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <th>Exception Cause </th>               
                  </tr>
                </thead>
```

**JS**

```
  this.standardOptions = DTOptionsBuilder;
  this.standardOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
     .fromFnPromise(('api/tables/datatables.standard.json').getList())

    //Add Bootstrap compatibility
    .withDOM("<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'l>r>" +
    "t" +
    "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>")
    .withBootstrap(); 

    this.standardColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('_id').withOption('defaultContent', '-'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('msg').withOption('defaultContent', '-'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('exception_cause').withOption('defaultContent', '-'),

  ];
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

In above screen shot only 100 page is coming. In 1 page has 10 records. Because restheart is not responding more then one thousand records.
So How can we fix pagination count and pagination thing. Because I can get again more then one thousand record after click on **next** button in pagination. But still count is same 1000(total count of records is 2000) the user will confused.

**For more understanding I am attaching screen shot.**
[image]

**Now it is coming like below:**
[image]

So I want to fix with flexible code. I don't have much experience in restheart and angular datatable.

Answer (score 0):

in restheart paging is controlled via two query parameters: **page** and **pagesize**

**pagesize** maximum value is 1000

have a look at official documentation about [paging](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/XACk#QueryDocuments-pagingPaging)

If you have 9000 documents, your requests can be:

```
GET /db/coll?pagesize=100&page=1
GET /db/coll?pagesize=100&page=2
....
GET /db/coll?pagesize=100&page=90
```

the following request will return no documents in the _embedded array:

```
GET /db/coll?pagesize=100&page=91
```

To count the existing documents you need to add the **count** query parameter:

```
GET /db/coll?pagesize=100&page=1&count
```

The total number of documents is returned in the **_size** property

Note that this also works if you specify the **filter** qparam, example:

```
GET /db/coll?pagesize=100&page=1&count&filter={"a":1}
```

Comment: If one adds the `hal=f` query parameter to each GET can also activate [HAL mode](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/RH/pages/9207888/Representation+Format#RepresentationFormat-Halmode) and get [pagination links](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/RH/pages/10747996/Query+Documents#QueryDocuments-pagingPaging).